How should I recover unused GAP insurance funds?
A few years ago a bought a new car from a Hyundai dealership with GAP insurance. It was all financed through Chase bank. This year I traded it in for another new car (different dealership). As part of the trade-in deal, I paid off the first car early and the new dealership said I was entitled to a refund on my unused GAP insurance that came with it.
So I contacted the first dealership about it, and the finance guy there had me submit some forms and proof of pay-off of the first car. He said to wait 8 weeks for a refund. So I waited the 8 weeks and none came. After that wait I recontacted the dealership and asked them what the hold-up might be. The finance guy said he submitted the forms to the financing bank, and that they were the ones who I should expect the refund from. So I contacted the bank, and they said that they do not handle the GAP refund because my account is closed.
So now I have the dealership and the bank pointing fingers at each-other, and no money in sight. The finance guy at the dealership is also very unresponsive. He rarely answers his phone or emails. What might I do, file a small claims suit against the dealership or the bank? By the way this was all in California, USA, if it matters.

Do you have any documentation on that insurance? What's the insurance company? You should probably talk to them. Small claims may be a problem, depending on the jurisdiction agreed upon in the contract, and it may not be worth your time at all.

Yes, apparently it's a "Toyota Financial Services" plan, even though it was a Hyundai. It does reiterate that cancellation is an option. It might be a good idea to contact them, since I've hit an impasse with the dealership.

Small claims court is an excellent option for this.  The more paperwork and documentation you can provide the better.  Do your best to clearly layout your case and timeline if it does go before a judge.  I am confident you can do this as your writing is clear.  Rehearse your presentation to a friend and see if they can follow your logic.
Now, if large companies were not idiots, involving a judge would not be necessary.  This would go before a mediator (required in many jurisdictions), they would say "oops" and pay your claim.  But they are, and they would rather have a 10K legal bill then pay you the few hundred dollars they owe.  Whatever.
If it was me, unless you have proof that they dealership provided the paperwork to the insurance company, I would name both in the suit.
In your suit, in addition to the amount owed be sure to also ask for:

Filling fees
Interest on the amount owed from the date it should have been paid until the current date
Any other costs incurred while playing their run around game.

